# Is there a way to read IP connection header inside server application in go?

Tags: go, grpc-go

Server application supports authentication which demands username and password from the client who is connecting with it. There can be a client from within the machine as well for which I do not want it to be authenticated. Client within the same machine connects with the server with the LOOPBACK address. What I want is that, if I can somehow apply filter for the destination IP of the gRPC connection and decide whether to apply authentication or not. Is there a way? Thanks !

```
func (s *RShellServer) ExecCmd(stream RShell_ExecCmdServer) error {
    # For example, something like this if condition.
    if (Conn().destination_ip != LOOPBACK) {
        if err, ok := gnmi.AuthorizeUser(stream.Context()); !ok {
                return fmt.Errorf("%s", err)
        }
    }
    req, err := stream.Recv()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("Error reading request: %s", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: DO you want some kind of middleware to filters IP before passing it on to grpc function?

Comment: Umm.. I want to put a filter for destination IP of that particular connection.
Something like this, ```if (Conn().destination_ip != LOOPBACK) {```(This is not valid syntactically, just want to execute something like that).
If this condition is true, I need to verify the authentication, else no authentication needed. Is there a way we can execute a condition like this?

Comment: I added a answer is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GRPC service should be something like this

```
func (MyServer) SomeFunction(ctx context.Context, 
    req *myserver.Request) (resp *myserver.Response, err error)
```

Then you can use peer library and extract peer information from context like `

```
p, err := peer.FromContext(ctx)
```

And get address from peer using

```
p.Addr
```

Comment: any import package required to use peer library?

Comment: It is in grpc library https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc/peer

Comment: Yes I tried that. It gives you the address of the peer end and I could live with it. Thanks. What I initially needed was to get the destination IP on which the peer connected. For example, Machine A communicates with Machine B(gRPC server), peer IP would be the IP of machine A. There can also be the case where, client can reside in machine B itself which will connect with gRPC server using a LOOPBACK ip.
In the end, I want to identify in the server, is client from localhost or an external peer?

Comment: I mean if you know peer IP you can writr a function to do that

Comment: I don't want the peer's IP, I want the IP on which peer has made the connection which is the server's IP. But, I assume if the client is from the localhost, the IP I am looking for would be "127.0.0.1" and if the client is not from the localhost, it would be the external facing IP of my server.
In short, what I want is that, peer has made the connection to "127.0.0.1" IP or "External facing IP of my gRPC server"?

Comment: But peer IP also should work for me in this specific use case.